# jQuery color picker function on change

Tags: jquery, forms, color-picker

So I'm writing a Wordpress plugin that generates a live preview upon changes to a php form using ajax. Everything is working great, but one little issue with jQuery is not quite right.

Normally, when you make add any text to a field and then press Enter or click another field, the a function in js is run to update the live preview.
For example:

```
$('#tst-bg_color').on('change.ChangeField', function(){--update preview function here--'});
```

Yet, I just changed one of my text fields into a Wordpress colorpicker. The field on my php form looks like this now:

```
<input type="button" name="tst-bg_color[color]" value="" id="tst-bg_color" />
```

So, not surprisingly this works the same way the other fields work in jQuery, meaning that when you click on another field, it finally runs the "update_preview" function in the jQuery above. However, I'd like to have it run the 'update preview' function each time a new color is selected without the user having to click on another field to update the preview.

I've tried the following, but none of them work:

```
$('#tst-bg_color').on('click.ChangeField', function(){--update preview function here--'});
```

and

```
$('#tst-bg_color').on('mouseup.ChangeField', function(){--update preview function here--'});
```

Not sure what else I can try to get this to trigger instantly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Er, `keydown`?!

Comment: Are you talking about the Colorpicker that ships with WP Core?

Comment: downvoted as this is a JS question, and therefor off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('yourColorpickerselector').wpColorPicker({
                        change: function(event, ui) {
                            var form = $(this).closest('form')
                            form .trigger('change')
                        }
                    });
```

within color picker default method "change". you can trigger form change. or any other function, what you want to do.

related link :
[wordpress discuss](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/) 
[iris color picker](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/)